# VueJs export table data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui, vue-data-tables

I am using [vue-data-tables](https://www.njleonzhang.com/vue-data-tables/#/) with [element-ui](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US) and I am looking for solution to export data from my tables.

#### Logic

I need to export data that are **placed in front-end table** and ***not the data that are returning from back-end***

> data in tables are limited as I needed while data from back-end are more complex and include variables that I don't need in excel file) that's why I'm looking for solution to export table data otherwise i would create back-end function for it.

#### Question/ Help request

Please if you have any previous experience with mentioned UI above tell me if I need to create manual function for it, or there is some package ready to work with `el-tables` ui, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think `json2csv` might be to one that you are looking for. Visit this link
[json2csv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json2csv)